# When will WSL2 be officially released?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I want to install docker on my windows subsystem for windows. In order to do that I need [WSL version 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index)

I am not able to upgrade from version 1 to version 2 I believe because the version of windows that I am running. I have OS Build 18363.836.

A lot of websites say that build 2004 was going to be available on May.I searched for wsl twitter account and I ended up here: 
https://twitter.com/i/lists/1131397802204864512

This post stated that it was goint to be rolled out on May 28 2020:
https://twitter.com/richturn_ms/status/1265872180396478466?s=20

Where can I find the official release date? Is the release date still unknown?

Comment: It's always hard to know why a post gets voted down when there are no comments to explain why.
My best guess would be that maybe some readers are annoyed with the Twitter links?
I don't know if that's the case, but I did find an alternative (non-Twitter) link – 
[WSL 2 will be generally available in Windows 10, version 2004](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl2-will-be-generally-available-in-windows-10-version-2004/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been rolled out since 27th May

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-2004

You can download it if it isn't offered through Windows Update

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

Comment: When I checked for updates on my windows computer it stated I had the latest version. This link solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ramhound Version upgrades use staged rollout, probably for MS to be able to pull them if serious problems surface. Upgrading from regular installation media is just as safe as via Windows Update. If there's a known hardware incompatibility, the installer will refuse to continue. (Ensuring your backups are working is a good idea anyway)

Answer (score 1):

"WSL 2 Support is coming to Windows 10 Versions 1903 and 1909"

> Support for Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 distros is being
> backported to Windows 10 version 1903, and 1909! Yes, you read that
> right. We heard how much you liked WSL 2 and wanted to expand its
> accessibility, and over the last few months we worked on bringing it
> back to 1903 and 1909.
>
> ...
>
> How do I get it? Currently, this backport to 1903 and 1909 will only
> be for x64 systems. If you are using an ARM64 version, please upgrade
> to Windows 10 version 2004 and you’ll gain full access to WSL 2.
>
> To get this backport you just need to check for updates. First open
> Windows Settings, navigate to ‘Update & Security’ and click Check for
> Updates. (more...)

[August 20, 2020 Microsoft (Windows Command Line)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/)